# How to create new GUID identity in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, guid, identity, profile

Good morning,
please, how can I re-create user's profile identity?
If non-register user make something, like create order with some profile's properties (like name, surname, phone,...), then he creates new one with new profile's properties, new values will rewrite old (save in database) properties... (this is how it behaves when the user uses the same browser) How can I generate complete new Identity GUID?

Comment: @downvoter please care to comment, people are looking for answers here

Comment: @oleksii it is unclear what is being asked. Also, he seems to asking about how to create a new guid, which has nothing to do with the rest of the question. A new guid is just `Guid.NewGuid`, but he seems to be asking for a lot more, like how to tie activities to a user before the user is created

Comment: can you make your question clear, I agree with @Oskar.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin @oleksii Ok, If I have user's profile with properties: Name and Surname. User sets this properties ("John","Doll"), then he save it. ASP.NET save this Identity into database, in db is one record: "John","Doll". And if same user next day sets "Jack","Foo" in database will be 2 records: 1# "Jack","Foo"; 2# "Jack","Foo". How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new user using the asp.net membership provider, it will automatically log in the new user. Try explicitly logging the user out after the call to create user or you can also try deleting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys, it looks like, i found solution! :)

```
AnonymousIdentificationSection tmp = new AnonymousIdentificationSection();
HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie(tmp.CookieName);
cookies.Domain = tmp.Domain;
cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
```

Thanks for your help!! :)